# jquery animate background color on scroll (multiple divs)

Tags: jquery, colors, background, jquery-animate, fade

so i am using this code from another question, with the jquery UI library

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#about").stop().animate({
       backgroundColor: $(window).scrollTop() > 200 ? '#000' : '#fff',
    }, 1000);
});
```

all the css is needed is

```
#about {background-color:#fff;}
```

this works perfectly, but i am trying to have the exact same effect, just with different colors on another div.

so i tried copy and pasting, and changing the settings but for some reason #contact fades in whenever the page is loaded, not when the user scrolls to the point.

my html is just 100% width and height stacked divs ontop of each other.

thank you!

*** JS FIDDLE ***

http://jsfiddle.net/xZyzv/

Comment: can you provide the HTML, CSS, and any other JavaScript/jQuery that you use.

Comment: can you please put a jsfiddle??

Comment: Please click "edit" and add the code that doesn't work. (Note also that when editing a question code should be indented by four spaces (or select it and press the `{}` button), don't use `>` which creates a block quote.)

Comment: i have provided the jsfiddle now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the JQuery file in your script, it will work. In your JSFIDDLE just change the framework and extension(left side) from "No Library(Pure js)" to "Jquery 1.6.4" and run the fiddle.

See my comment to know why you can see the fading effect only when you scroll fast.

You can use this javascript to see the fading effect when you reach the #contact div.

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        $("#about").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor: $(window).scrollTop() > 200 ? '#000' : '#fff',
        }, 1000);
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 500){
    $("#contact").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor: $(window).scrollTop() > 500 ? '#fff' : '#000',
        }, 1000);
    }

    });
```

Comment: thank you for your help, #about is fading good, but not the #contact div

Comment: if i scroll slowly down the page and let #about fade in, then continue scrolling it doesn't work. but if i scroll down really really fast it works

Comment: As soon as you start to scroll, the animate function on "#contact" is getting triggered and completes itself in 1 second. So when you scroll fast and reach the #contact div within 1 second, you are able to see the fading effect. And when u r scrolling slow the fading effect gets completed before you reach #contact div.

Comment: ah i see. so the #about works perfect, but is there anyway to make #contact fade when you reach the div, not when the page starts scrolling? i am new to jquery sorry

Comment: I have already given the code, please see the answer. Use that code to see the fading when you reach near #contact.

Comment: your jsfiddle works perfect, i can not thank enough Devjit!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I added the same function to the other divs. Maybe the value of 200 in the scroll should be adapted so it would fade only when you are near that div.

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/HdvQ9/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $("#home").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor: $(window).scrollTop() > 200 ? '#00f' : '#fff',
        }, 1000);
    });
$(window).scroll(function() {
        $("#about").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor: $(window).scrollTop() > 200 ? '#0f0' : '#fff',
        }, 1000);
    });

$(window).scroll(function() {
        $("#contact").stop().animate({
          backgroundColor: $(window).scrollTop() > 200 ? '#0ff' : '#f00',
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: how would this be possible? to change the 200 so it would only fade when you are near the div? sorry, completely new to jquery

Comment: I mean different divs can have animation when scroll is more near them. On the example above all animation starts at scroll 200, but look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/HdvQ9/4/

Comment: thank you, is there any way to set it in percent not pixels? like contact is positioned 300% from the top, so is there a way instead of using 500 pixels, to use 300%?

Comment: Yes, you just have to calculate how much is in %. But 500% is more than the height, you mean 50% or? check here: http://jsfiddle.net/6bvvU/